# Find a branch of the logarithm at the region $\mathbb C \setminus S$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Find a branch of the logarithm at the region $\mathbb C \setminus S$, where

$$S\ := \{(1+i)t :  t \geq 0 \}.$$

I tried it by Fundamental theorem of contour integration but I don't get suitable closed path $\gamma$ for which $\int_{\gamma} f(z)\ dz \neq 0$ as in the case of showing there is no branch of logarithm in $\mathbb C \setminus \{0 \}$ I get $\gamma (t) = e^{it},$ $0 \leq t \leq 2 \pi$.

So how can I tackle it? Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to construct this branch.

Assume that you know the existence of the main branch of logarithm

Log$:\mathbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]\to\mathbb C$,

with argument in the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$.

Observe next that if 
$U=\mathbb C\setminus\{(i+i)t:t\ge 0\}$, and $h(z)=\mathrm{e}^{3\pi i/4}z$, then $h: U\to \mathbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]$ is biholomorphic (1-1, onto, holomorphic and its inverse as well).

Define $\lambda : U\to\mathbb C$, with
$$
\lambda(z)=\mathrm{Log}\big(h(z)\big)-\frac{3\pi i}{4}.
$$
Clearly, $\lambda$ is holomorphic, as a composition of holomorphic functions, and
$$
\exp\big(\lambda(z)\big)=\exp\left(\mathrm{Log}\big(h(z)\big)-\frac{3\pi i}{4}\right)=\exp\left(\mathrm{Log}\big(h(z)\big)\right)
\exp\left(-\frac{3\pi i}{4}\right)=h(z)\exp\left(-\frac{3\pi i}{4}\right)=z.
$$
So, indeed, $\lambda(z)$ is a branch of logarithm in $U$.

In fact, for every $k\in\mathbb Z$, $\lambda(z)+2k\pi i$,  is also a branch.

Comment: Excellent work @
Yiorgos S. Smyrlis. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There is a complex number $c$ such that $cz$ belongs to the negative real axis if and only if $z$ is in $S.$
[ $c=e^{5i\pi/4}$].

If Log denotes the principal branch of logarithm, then Log$(cz)$ is an analytic branch of log for $S.$